# HTML Formating of text in xml element

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I currently am formatting my xml using an XSLT style sheet. it looks a little something like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="Talents">
    <div style="font-family:Calibri, Arial; font-size:5pt; cursor: default;">
<xsl:if test="Talent != ''">
    <table border="0" width="650">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 15px;" bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%">

            <b id="toggle"><xsl:value-of select="Talent"/></b></td>

            <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="20%" align="center">
                <xsl:value-of select="TCost"/>
                <xsl:text>  -  </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
// etc
```

so formatting XML elements into a nice structured table is fairly easy. I would like to know how if at all possible you can format the actual text in those elements.

for instance you dont know the content thats in the element Tyep but can you have html elemtns in it so that if you see a  around text it makes it bold etc?

So my question is can you html format text withing a xml element?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<Collection>
     <Talents>
     <Talent>Smiling</Talent>
     <TCost>1</TCost>
     <Type>ANY king of smile will do but the fake ones are the bed</Type>
     </Talents>
```

What I am looking at is in  is it possible to have html formats like bold underline different text color? if so how do I perform this so that when i open my xml it is styled with my style.xsl and then the text inside the xml element also has html formatting.

Comment: Yes, definitely. What does your input XML look like?

Comment: Please post your input XML and your desired output.

Comment: its just normal text inside elements. I have updated the above with an example

Answer (score 0):

I tried to crate an working example which hopefully will answer your question:

To have content with xlm or html tags copied you have to a an "identity transform template" to your xslt file.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And change from `xsl:value-of` to `apply-templates`. (Only were you like to have copies of the whole child tree).

The xsl will look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Collection" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Collection">
    <xsl:for-each select="Talents">
        <div style="font-family:Calibri, Arial; font-size:5pt; cursor: default;">
            <xsl:if test="Talent != ''">
                <table border="0" width="650">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left: 15px;" bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%">

                            <b id="toggle">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Talent"/>
                            </b>
                        </td>

                        <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="20%" align="center">
                            <xsl:value-of select="TCost"/>
                            <xsl:text>  -  </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Type/node()"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </xsl:if>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you can add html to the Type tag. With this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <Collection>
        <Talents>
            <Talent>Smiling</Talent>
            <TCost>1</TCost>
            <Type>ANY <b>king</b> of smile will do but the fake ones are the bed</Type>
        </Talents>
    </Collection>
<xml>
```

It will generate this output:

```
<div style="font-family: Calibri, Arial; font-size: 5pt; cursor: default;">

        <table border="0" width="650">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left: 15px;" bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%">
                    <b id="toggle">Smiling</b>
                </td>
                <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="20%" align="center">
                    1 - ANY <b>king</b> of smile will do but the fake ones are the bed
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```